# Decrease Audio of Spotify while another Application is playing a Sound

Tags: android, audio, spotify, xiaomi, miui

I want to use my phone as a cheap Soundboard meaning that I want to listen to Spotify and simultaneously open another App and play short mp3 files.

This works fine but both Audio sources are played at 100% volume. I would like Spotify to either

- stop while the other Audio source is active but then resume again if it is finished
- or decrease its Volume while the other Audio source is playing.

I am using a Xiamoi with MIUI Global 13.0.8 Stable and found the following settings, but even with Multiple audio sources not enabled both sources play at 100 % volume.

I am happy for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Apps need to support [Audio Ducking](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#automatic_ducking). Be aware that SO is for programming questions. power user questions belong on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=audio+ducking)